# Parsing SEC RSS Title field using regex

Tags: python, regex

All, I have an RSS feed from the SEC with company title as follows; e.g.,

> 10-Q - What ever INC (0000123456) (Filer)

so the general structure is:

form_name + whitespace + dash + whitespace + **company_name** + " (" + **SIC_Number** + ") (Filer)"

I need to extract the **company_name** and **SIC_Number**. Note the form_name can have a dash, and the company name will have white spaces and dashes. 
This can be done (I'm using python) by using the re.split function for the dashes, and again for the brackets, but it's ugly (showing for completeness):

```
m = re.split('[()]',re.split(' - ',str)[-1])
```

What would the proper RegEx be?

Comment: I’m assuming the company name can not contain dashes?

Comment: Company title CAN have dashes, but this will only happen after the whitespace+dash+whitespace combination after the form name..

Comment: Can the company name or the form name contain " - "?

Comment: yes, SEC form names can be pretty much anything they want, 10-Q, 10-K/A (for amendments to financial statements..), 4, etc. There's no structure here. Company names are not restricted either and can have dashes. In the meantime, i'm getting good results with the expression you provided below. Thanks!

Comment: That expression will break as soon as the company name contains the string " - " (dash surrounded by spaces). But if you can’t guarantee that either the company name ro the form name will never contain that string, that thing is actually unparsable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the company name does not contain the string " - ", the SIC Number is only numbers and there is a space before the opening bracket, this is what you are looking for:

```
m = re.search(r' - ([^(]+?) \((\d+)\)',t)
```

Comment: this works, but of course I immediately encountered a company name that has dashes.. question revised accordingly.. sorry.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.